# Remote SSH access to sleeping MacBook Pro only works when 'Find my Mac' application is running - can I make this persist?

Tags: sleep-wake, ssh, find-my-mac

As expected, I cannot SSH in to my MacBook when I have left it with the lid shut/sleeping, but if I use my iPhone to access 'Find my Mac', the MacBook wakes and then I can SSH in.

However, when my iPhone goes to sleep/I quit 'Find my Mac', the SSH connection hangs.

Is it possible to use 'Find my Mac' to wake my MacBook for SSH and then have this connection persist after I close 'Find my Mac'?

Comment: Is the macbook plugged in ? See Power saver settings in Sys Pref

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36690/how-can-i-prevent-an-ssh-session-from-hanging-in-os-x-terminal?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251221/how-can-i-prevent-mac-terminal-ssh-from-disconnecting-when-the-screen-is-automat?rq=1  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120639/how-can-i-stop-my-macbook-pro-from-automatically-sleeping-when-i-lock-the-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried out caffeinate?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stacke