# ssh session disconnecting on screen dimming on macOs monterey when on battery

Tags: macos, terminal, battery, ssh

I am having an issue keeping ssh connections alive on macOS Monterey when using battery. whenever the screen shuts down or I manually lock the screen all connections stop and upon resuming my ssh session is frozen and I have to reconnect again.

I have tried all options in battery settings but to no success, it keeps shutting down any connection have instantly

I am running an m1 pro 16" macbook, if that's useful info

Comment: In System Preferences > Battery, is the option "Low power mode" enabled in the "Battery" section? If it is, could you disable it and test?

Comment: @jaume nope it's not up

Comment: How long do you leave it before resuming, seconds, minutes?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths minutes, sometimes the connection stoped the second the screen dimmed

Comment: I know that ssh apps on iOS do something similar, Prompt 2 on my old iPad will disconnect, but I think that's more an accepted behaviour for an iOS app. I tried a battery only ssh on my M1 MBP (12.5) and shut the lid for a few minutes. The ssh session survived running top on the remote side, indicating the MBP didn't enter a proper sleep. Nothing showed in pmset on the MBP, though not my area of expertise. Sorry I can't help further, but if you want to avoid some of the hassle of the disconnect you could consider using tmux or similar on the remote so that you have a resumable session.

Comment: See also the highest scored answer re. ssh timeouts for this question. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251221/how-can-i-prevent-mac-terminal-ssh-from-disconnecting-when-the-screen-is-automat?rq=1&answertab=scoredesc#tab-top Also, is there anything special about the ssh server configuration on the remote which may be contributing to a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

For me with my M1, the problem was linked to power saving mode in which the Mac puts the device to sleep when the screensaver is on after a specified timeout. Mine was 5 minutes on the power adapter. So a short time to have the ssh session / VPN disconnect.

The options as listed [re. ssh timeouts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251221/how-can-i-prevent-mac-terminal-ssh-from-disconnecting-when-the-screen-is-automat?rq=1&answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) , didn't help me as the device going to sleep stopped network devices and applications

**System Preferences** > **Battery** > **Power Adapter** > **Prevent your Mac from automatically sleeping when the display is off**.

You don't have the same option for the Battery mode.

[image: Screenshot of the Battery preferences window showing the Power Adapter options]